# Child view controller resizes when I reopen the height

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 view controllers which I would like to embed inside a scrollview, snapchat style (so you can swipe between them). But I'm facing a really weird problem where the nav bar appears squished against the status bar,

[image: squished image]

but when I leave the app (go to home screen for example) and come back, it moves down.

[image: normal nav bar]

Here's my code:

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

        self.mainScrollView.delaysContentTouches = false

        let v1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as! profileViewController

        self.addChildViewController(v1)
        self.mainScrollView.addSubview(v1.view)
        v1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        //--------

        let v2 : recordViewController = recordViewController(nibName: "recordViewController", bundle: nil)

        self.addChildViewController(v2)
        self.mainScrollView.addSubview(v2.view)
        v2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        //--------

        let v3 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "discoverViewController") as! discoverViewController

        self.addChildViewController(v3)
        self.mainScrollView.addSubview(v3.view)
        v3.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


        //--------
        var v1frame : CGRect = self.mainScrollView.bounds
        v1frame.origin.x = 0
        v1.view.frame = v1frame
        //v1.view.bindFrameToSuperviewBounds()

        var v2frame : CGRect = self.mainScrollView.bounds
        v2frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        v2.view.frame = v2frame

        var v3frame : CGRect = self.mainScrollView.bounds
        v3frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width*2
        v3.view.frame = v3frame
```

My solutions so far have been programmatically adding constraints, but I can't figure out what I should add constraints to. Here's what I tried

```
    let csH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[v]-0-|", options: [], metrics: [:], views: ["v": recordView])
    let csV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[v]-0-|", options: [], metrics: [:], views: ["v": recordView])

    view.addConstraints(csH)
    view.addConstraints(csV)
```

Comment: How is `mainScrollView` constrained? Why are you not giving `v1.view` etc. any frame?

Comment: @matt mainScrollView is constrained in storyboard. It has top, bottom, leading and trailing guides to the view controller

Answer (score -2):

Select the field you want to edit. Make settings like the picture. I hope it helps.

[image: Image Click]
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­